# En que casos trabajar con JPA y que otros casos utilizar propiamente JDBC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Saludos no se si se pueden hacer este tipo de preguntas en SO, de antemano una disculpa si no, me gustaría saber de gente que trabaje con estas tecnologías, en cual debo enfocarme mas, cuales son las ventajas y desventajas de cada uno y por su puesto laboralmente hablando que es lo que se utiliza mas.

Realmente JPA es una tecnología que me ha gustado mucho pero mucha gente me dice que no la utilice, que ralentiza la aplicación.

agradecería una su ayuda y opiniones en este tema.

Comment: Aunque interesante, las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones. He votado para su cierre.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer las etiquetas que pusiste, muchas veces traen orientación de uso y bastante informaicón para iniciar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA te va dar mas control sobre tu codigo ya que todo queda mas elegante pero si, definitivamente usar un ORM es una capa mas que pones en tu proceso, una caja negra de alguna forma.

Yo en particular la he utilizado muchísimo (Hibernate) pero mayormente para catálogos, cuando se trata de queries muy pesadas (Solo me ha pasado un par de veces) intento usar queries directos con JDBC para salvar la mayor cantidad de performance posible.

Pero en general te recomiendo que uses JPA, lo he usado para muchos proyectos de todo tipo y me ha funcionado perfecto.

Comment: Gracias Gemasoft, también quisiera consultarte si no es molestia, para auténticacion y Login igualmente me recomiendas JPA sobre JDBC directo?.

Answer (score 2):

No es por nada pero JPA es otro mundo con respecto a JDBC. JPA lo que te permite es tener un codigo mas limpio, como dijeron los compañeros anteriores. Ademas de esto, permite manejar consultas sin escribir codigo SQL, aumentando en parte la seguridad de la aplicacion.

El otro nivel y que es el que yo utilizo es un ORM, utilizo Hibernate y es otra vida. Eso si, requiere cierto nivel de aprendizaje pero no es tan fuerte si has manejado JPA.

JDBC se suele utilizar para aplicaciones que consumen recursos de una red local, ya que se tiene cierto control de seguridad en estos entornos. Para el resto de aplicaciones se utiliza o JPA u ORM como Hibernate. Este ultimo es bastante utilizado en paginas y servicios webs.

Answer (score 1):

Un JPA te va a ofrece muchas ventajas sobre tu código, la principal para mi es la de poder realizar consultas sin tener que escribir SQL, en mi experiencia siempre pasa que van errores de sintaxis cuando escriben querys que te obligan a hacer un re-deploy a tu aplicación. Quizá el mayor contra es tener otra capa mas de abstraction que te podría generar uso mayor de recursos. En conclusion si te recomendaría usar un JPA aunque te pueda consumir mas recursos los beneficios que te pueden ofrecer valen la pena y en casos en que el tiempo de respuesta sea crucial cambiar a JDBC.